# OpenGL object distortion

Tags: opengl, matrix, opengl-3

I'm trying to display a triangle on the screen and move around with keyboard+mouse, but the closer the object is to the edge of the screen, the more it stretches.
Here's the relevant code:

```
fieldOfView = 45;
x += mouseSpeed * deltaTime * deltaMouseX
y += mouseSpeed * deltaTime * deltaMouseY

position = glm::vec3(0,0,5);
forward = glm::vec3(cos(y) * sin (x),
                              sin(y),
                              cos(y) * cos(x));

right = glm::vec3(sin(x - 3.14f/2.0f),
                            0,
                            cos(x - 3.14f/2.0f));

up = glm::cross(right,forward);

projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(fieldOfView, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(position,position + forward, up);
```

this is updated every frame. In my vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vert,1)
```

where vert is my object coordinates, projection is my projectionMatrix, and view is my viewMatrix. I have a feeling the problem is with my viewmatrx, but I can't find anything wrong with it. Let me know if you need more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(fieldOfView, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

The fieldofView specifies the field of view angle, in degrees, in the y direction (describes the angular extent of a given scene that is imaged by a camera).For a given camera–subject distance, longer lenses (small FOV) magnify the subject more. For a given subject magnification (and thus different camera–subject distances), longer lenses (less FOV) appear to compress distance; wider lenses (more FOV) appear to expand the distance between objects.

Another result of using a wide angle lens is a greater apparent perspective distortion when the camera is not aligned perpendicularly to the subject: parallel lines converge at the same rate as with a normal lens, but converge more due to the wider total field. For example, buildings appear to be falling backwards much more severely when the camera is pointed upward from ground level than they would if photographed with a normal lens at the same distance from the subject, because more of the subject building is visible in the wide-angle shot.So,the wider fov you have,the most distortion you detect.

How is yours initialized?

A normal FOV angle is 45.

Comment: It's set to 45, however you helped me fix the issue. I found out today that C++ doesn't let you call constructors in constructors, but the compiler is silent about it. Because of this, fieldOfView was set to 0 and I had no idea.